# WiX 3.0: Basic one dialog installer

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I would like to create a setup with three basic dialogs (one input dialog):

- Browse (next + exit button)
- Progress
- Finish

No welcome dialog or any other unnecessary dialog. Maybe even combine 1&2, but I would like to stick to predefined dialogs for the moment.

I looked at WixUI_Minimal, but couldn't figure out how to modify the sequence of dialogs so that my specification is met.

Links or informations are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [SharpSetup](http://sharpsetup.eu/) to create such minimal installer (dialogs can be graphically edited in Visual Studio designer). It requires .NET at runtime - not sure if it is acceptable in your case.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of SharpSetup.